# Ending the setup when all components have been installed in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to make my setup stop when all components are already install.

Installation Example :

1. First Install : one component install
2. Second Install : install the rest of component
3. Third install : setup begin and go directly to `wpFinished` page or stop and put a message saying "all component are already install".

I've make some research here and on other website and I have do the following :

```pascal
procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  Confirm := False;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  ItemIndex: Integer;
  InstallEn: String;
  InstallFr: String;
  InstallDe: String;
  CompDescEnIndex: Integer;
  CompDescFrIndex: Integer;
  CompDescDeIndex: Integer;
  Check: Integer;
begin
    # This part is to make not selectable component already install
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\COMPANY\{#RegProduct}\{#RegCurVer}', 'Install-ENG', InstallEn) then  
        if ((InstallEn = 'International Pack' )
        or (InstallEn = 'Pack International')
        or (InstallEn = 'International Paket'))
            then
                ItemIndex := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.IndexOf(CustomMessage('CompDescEn'));
                WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[ItemIndex] := False;
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\COMPANY\{#RegProduct}\{#RegCurVer}', 'Install-FRA', InstallFr) then
        if ((InstallFr = 'French Pack') 
        or (InstallFr = 'Pack France')
        or (InstallFr = 'Franzosisch Paket'))
            then
                ItemIndex := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.IndexOf(CustomMessage('CompDescFr'));
                WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[ItemIndex] := False;
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\COMPANY\{#RegProduct}\{#RegCurVer}', 'Install-DEU', InstallDe) then  
        if ((InstallDe = 'German Pack')
        or (InstallDe = 'Pack Allemand')
        or (InstallDe = 'Deutsches Paket'))
            then
                ItemIndex := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.IndexOf(CustomMessage('CompDescDe'));
                WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[ItemIndex] := False;
    # After I try to say if all component are install, close the wizard.
    CompDescEnIndex := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.IndexOf(CustomMessage('CompDescEn'));
    CompDescFrIndex := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.IndexOf(CustomMessage('CompDescFr'));
    CompDescDeIndex := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.IndexOf(CustomMessage('CompDescDe'));
    if not WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[CompDescEnIndex]
        and not WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[CompDescFrIndex]
        and not WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[CompDescDeIndex]
    then 
        Check := 1;
    if (Check <> 0) then
        WizardForm.Close;
end;
```

**Note:** Code may not be very clean, I started in Pascal + Inno Setup in the `Code` section.

If all my component are installed (and not selectable), I want the wizard to stop and not continue...

I can't find a solution to go directly at `wpFinished` page... Is there a way to do that?

How can I stop the wizard if all component are installed because `WizardForm.Close;` seems not work in my case?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot skip to the `wpFinished` page as Inno Setup does not allow you to skip the `wpReady` page to avoid creating a fully-automated installers (which might be abused).

---

You can create a custom "finished" page though:

[image]

```pascal
procedure AllInstalledPageActivate(Sender: TWizardPage);
begin
  { Change the "Next" button to "Finish" on our custom page }
  WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish);
  { Hide the "Cancel" button }
  WizardForm.CancelButton.Visible := False;
end;

procedure ExitProcess(uExitCode: UINT);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function AllInstalledPageNextButtonClick(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  { Abort the installer when the "Finish" button is clicked on our custom page }
  ExitProcess(0);
  Result := True; { shut up the compiler warning }
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Caption: TLabel;
  AllInstalledPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  ...

  { If everything is installed already ... }
  if IsEverythingInstalled then
  begin 
    { ... create a custom "everything is installed" page }
    AllInstalledPage :=
      CreateCustomPage(
        wpWelcome, 'All components are installed already',
        'There''s nothing to install.');

    AllInstalledPage.OnActivate := @AllInstalledPageActivate;
    AllInstalledPage.OnNextButtonClick := @AllInstalledPageNextButtonClick;

    Caption := TLabel.Create(AllInstalledPage);
    Caption.Caption :=
      'Everything is installed already. Click Finish to close the installer.';
    Caption.Width := AllInstalledPage.SurfaceWidth;
    Caption.Parent := AllInstalledPage.Surface;
  end;
end;
```

---

Even simpler solution is to use a plain [message box](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_msgbox).

---

The `Wizard.Close` would close the installer, it would not go to the "Finished" page anyway. If you really want to abort the installer, return `False` from [`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) (you would need to move some of your code to the `InitializeSetup`).

Or use the [`ExitProcess` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess), as in my example.